# Filtering the retrieved JSON data from Azure Infinity

Tags: azure-devops, grafana

I want to only include those servers that are currently in Optimization state.
What I am currently doing is, I am pulling JSON response from a swagger endpoint where the data source is Azure Infinity JSON looks like following below
A server is said to be in Optmization state if ServerState=5

```
"parser": "simple",
      "refId": "A",
      "root_selector": "",
      "source": "url",
      "type": "json",
      "url": "https://abcde.net/ServerState/GetLatestServerStates",
      "url_options": {
        "body_content_type": "text/plain",
        "body_type": "raw",
        "data": "",
        "method": "POST"
```

[image: -]

I tried changing the query to `https://abcde.net/ServerState/GetLatestServerStates?ServerState=5` it still returns all the types of servers ie 1,2,3,4 that are closed, data servers, and two more whereas I want the query to filter the result such that it only returns the server that are in ServerState=5 nothing helped, also tried adding filters to the targets field but it just threw me an error stating `(e.value || []).map is not a function`